# Reports in SSRS with additional parameters

Tags: c#, sql, reporting-services, reporting

I can create reports with parameters in SQL reporting services and use them in C#(reportviewer), but now I have a problem. I have to create report with not only required parameters, but also with additional parameters - checkboxes(boolean). But this isnt the problem.

**The problem is here:** How to build reports, which use different stored procedures(datasets) according to values of additional checkboxes? It is possible do it in Reporting Services or it can be done later in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build dynamic string queries in query expression window, for example:

```
=Iif(SomeParameter!Value = true, "query1", "query2")
```

But beware if you have many conditions and parameters as debugging gets more and more tedious.

Comment: I have many parameters and conditions. And... in procedures are not same output data

Comment: SSRS will handle different data returned, all you have to do is reference every column returned in "output columns" tab. If there is a column which is not returned by the query, it will just be an empty value. As for many conditions, if you think you will be able to control the query, you can still go for it, after all there is a reason people invented code comments :) On a sidenote - building reports is often a struggle between "Squeeze as much information in one report" and "Keep the report easy to maintain". If you want simple reports, separate them into several smaller.

Comment: Ok, thank You for answer! I've already known it all, but sometimes think comes to mind: "maybe there is another decision" :)